# DataView - what is node attribute (ext-3.2.0) in Extjs 4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs3

In old extjs 3.2.0, `DataView` has function like

```
click: function(view, index, node, e) {
     Ext.get(node);
}
```

in extjs 4.1 that change to

```
itemclick: function( view, record, item, index, e, eOpts ) {
     Ext.get(item); //not the same with Ext.get(node);
}
```

But `Ext.get(item)` not the same with `Ext.get(node)` . what is the `node` attribute in extjs 4.1 thanks

Comment: `item` is the element. Why is it not what you're looking for?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli b/c i look a example using `extjs3.2.0` has `menu.show(Ext.get(node));` but i using `ex4.1` and that's not working?

Comment: `show` when passing an element isn't supported in 4.x.

Comment: In Ext 4 use `menu.showAt(e.getXY())`